# Spring Batch - How to return exit code from an application that uses JobParameters?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, exit-code

I have a spring batch application, where some jobs are executed. It works normally, but at this moment, I need it to return error codes in the command prompt (shell) according to some conditions:

for example:

- if the job executed correctly: code 1
- if the job did not execute because the file sent by parameter does not exist: code 2
- if the job did not run because an exception was thrown internally: code 3

Currently, even when the job is successful, the exit code is not displayed in the terminal. Just the standard information from the spring batch itself.

My Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("file:/my-properties.properties")
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
   
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;
    
    @Bean
    ExitCodeExceptionMapper exitCodeExceptionMapper() {
      return exception -> {
        if (exception.getCause() instanceof MyEntityNotFoundException) {
          return 3;
        }
        return 1;
      };
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args)));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
       JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("file", args[1]).toJobParameters(); 

       jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);   
    }
}
```

So, in summary, the application looks like this:

I run the batch via command line passing a parameter (file), and the job processes it. In this processing, I need to make sure that when any exception is thrown, the exit code is 3 (in the test above I put it only when the entity does not exist in the database). I've done a lot of research on this, but I still can't get the exit codes to show up in the console.

Thanks for helping!